# Display the content of a memory stream in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xslt, stream

I'm working on a MVC project which creates a memory stream which is used for XSLT Transform. At the end, I want to display the results of the transformation on any web browser.
Following is memory stream is being created.

```
       XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
       xsl.Load(xsltpath);    
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
       xsl.Transform(InputMessagePath, xmlWriter);
       xmlWriter.Close();
       // Pass or set the content of stream as a string or any other compatible type to the view to diplay
       stream.Close();
```

Is it possible to display the contents of a memory stream in a web browser? If it's not possible what would be the best way to do that? I'm thinking about creating temporary file and  pass its path to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path) as a parameter. But before that, it would be great to know the possibility of using the the stream object instead of creating a file to display the contents in a web browser.
Thank you.

Comment: So it sounds your XSLT does something with the memory stream to produce HTML that you would like to display as a web page. Is that right?

Comment: Yes.. I have updated the post by adding the code segment which creates the memory stream. I can set the stream or its content as a string in the model. I'm trying to display them in a new web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You return a 'FileResult' and set content-type in the response:

You can find documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

There's an overload that takes a stream.

return File(stream, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Thanks... I used this method to save the memorystream. It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies. Just thought that it would be useful for someone, if I posted my implementation.

Following is procedure I used to display the content of memorystream. My requirement was to get the encoded html content of XSLT transform and display in a browser. Following is not exactly what I implemented. I simplified it to demonstrate the above requirement.

------------- Model ----------------------------------------

```
public class MyModel
 {
    public string EncodedOutputMessage { get; set; }

    Public Transform()
    {
        // Do something
        SetTransformResult(xsl, intputMsgPath);
    }

    private void SetTransformResult(XslCompiledTransform xsl, string intputMsgPath)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
        xsl.Transform(intputMsgPath, xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Close();

        XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();
        stream.Position = 0; // rewind the pointer to the beginning of the stream
        root.Load(stream);
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.GetElementsByTagName("BodyXhtml");
        if (nodes.Count == 1)
        {
            EncodedOutputMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(nodes[0].InnerXml);
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

-------------- Controller -----------------------------------

```
public class MyTestController : Controller
{   
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowResult()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Transform();
        ViewBag.DecodedOutputMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.EncodedOutputMessage);
        return View("MyView");
    }
}
```

----- MyView --------------------------------------------------------------

```
@model Tester.Models.MyModel
// Other fields to display
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DecodedOutputMessage);
```

The action method do the transform and get the encoded string, then decode it and send it to the view. I have removed most of the methods to simplify this procedure.

If you don't have any other content to display in the browser, you can pass only the HTML string, something like this.

```
 public string Result()
    {
        string htmlRes = "<html><body><font color=\"red\"> Testing color... </font></body></html>";
        return htmlRes ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(Server.MapPath("~/NFCe.xsl"));
transform.Transform(document, null, writer);
Response.Write(writer.ToString());
```

Th XML result is sent to the client. In that case I have a variable 'xml' with my original xml, them I'm applying a transformation contained in the file NFCE.xsl. The Response.Write writes a string to the output stream, which is sent to the client, instead of the rendered aspx.